# P3DFFT library installation

Tags: software-installation, make

I am installing P3DFFT on HPC. I am using the following configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/TMA_CFDLab/174100022/software --enable-single --enable-fftw --with-fftw=/opt/cray/pe/fftw/default/x86_64 FC=ftn CC=cc
```

At the end of configure I get the message `configure: configure script complete!`.
When I run `make`, I get the error as given below.

Please help me on this error.
It is the first time I am istalling P3DFFT on HPC ( High Performance COmputing )

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E71xT.png)

Error

```
174100022@nid00077:~/software/p3dfft-2.7.6> make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/TMA_CFDLab/174100022/software/p3dfft-2.7.6'
Making all in build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/TMA_CFDLab/174100022/software/p3dfft-2.7.6/build'
ftn -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/opt/cray/pe/fftw/default/x86_64/include   -DSINGLE_PREC -DMEASURE -DFFTW -g -O2 -c -o fft_spec.o fft_spec.F90
No supported cpu target is set, CRAY_CPU_TARGET=x86-64 will be used.
Load a valid targeting module or set CRAY_CPU_TARGET
ftn -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/opt/cray/pe/fftw/default/x86_64/include   -DSINGLE_PREC -DMEASURE -DFFTW -g -O2 -c -o module.o module.F90
No supported cpu target is set, CRAY_CPU_TARGET=x86-64 will be used.
Load a valid targeting module or set CRAY_CPU_TARGET
ftn -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/opt/cray/pe/fftw/default/x86_64/include   -DSINGLE_PREC -DMEASURE -DFFTW -g -O2 -c -o fft_init.o fft_init.F90
No supported cpu target is set, CRAY_CPU_TARGET=x86-64 will be used.
Load a valid targeting module or set CRAY_CPU_TARGET
ftn -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/opt/cray/pe/fftw/default/x86_64/include   -DSINGLE_PREC -DMEASURE -DFFTW -g -O2 -c -o fft_exec.o fft_exec.F90
No supported cpu target is set, CRAY_CPU_TARGET=x86-64 will be used.
Load a valid targeting module or set CRAY_CPU_TARGET
ftn -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/opt/cray/pe/fftw/default/x86_64/include   -DSINGLE_PREC -DMEASURE -DFFTW -g -O2 -c -o wrap.o wrap.F90
No supported cpu target is set, CRAY_CPU_TARGET=x86-64 will be used.
Load a valid targeting module or set CRAY_CPU_TARGET
rm -f libp3dfft.a
ar cru libp3dfft.a fft_spec.o module.o fft_init.o fft_exec.o wrap.o 
ranlib libp3dfft.a
Makefile:589: recipe for target 'all-local' failed
make[2]: [all-local] Error 1 (ignored)
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/TMA_CFDLab/174100022/software/p3dfft-2.7.6/build'
Making all in sample
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/TMA_CFDLab/174100022/software/p3dfft-2.7.6/sample'
Making all in FORTRAN
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/TMA_CFDLab/174100022/software/p3dfft-2.7.6/sample/FORTRAN'
ftn -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../include/   -DSINGLE_PREC -DMEASURE -DFFTW -I../../include/  -g -O2 -c -o driver_sine_many.o driver_sine_many.F90
No supported cpu target is set, CRAY_CPU_TARGET=x86-64 will be used.
Load a valid targeting module or set CRAY_CPU_TARGET

      use p3dfft
          ^      
ftn-292 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 55, Column = 11 
  "P3DFFT" is specified as the module name on a USE statement, but the compiler cannot find it.

      real(p3dfft_type), dimension(:,:,:,:),  allocatable :: BEG,C
           ^                                                       
ftn-113 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 64, Column = 12 
  IMPLICIT NONE is specified in the local scope, therefore an explicit type must be specified for data object "P3DFFT_TYPE".
           ^                                                       
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 64, Column = 12 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      complex(p3dfft_type), dimension(:,:,:,:),  allocatable :: AEND
              ^                                                      
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 65, Column = 15 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      real(p3dfft_type) twopi
           ^                  
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 66, Column = 12 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      integer(i8) Ntot
              ^        
ftn-113 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 68, Column = 15 
  IMPLICIT NONE is specified in the local scope, therefore an explicit type must be specified for data object "I8".
              ^        
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 68, Column = 15 
  "I8" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      real(p3dfft_type) factor
           ^                   
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 69, Column = 12 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      real(p3dfft_type),dimension(:,:),allocatable:: sinx,siny,sinz
           ^                                                        
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 70, Column = 12 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      real(i8) rtime1,rtime2,Nglob
           ^                       
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 71, Column = 12 
  "I8" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      real(i8) gt(12,3),gtcomm(3),tc
           ^                         
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 72, Column = 12 
  "I8" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      timers = 0.0
      ^            
ftn-113 crayftn: ERROR FFT3D, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 88, Column = 7 
  IMPLICIT NONE is specified in the local scope, therefore an explicit type must be specified for data object "TIMERS".

    real(p3dfft_type) C(istart(1):iend(1),istart(2):iend(2),istart(3):iend(3),nv)
         ^                                                                        
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR CHECK_RES, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 295, Column = 7 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

    real(p3dfft_type) sinyz,cdiff,ccdiff,ans,prec
         ^                                        
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR CHECK_RES, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 296, Column = 7 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

 20      continue
         ^        
ftn-241 crayftn: WARNING CHECK_RES, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 310, Column = 10 
  The nonblock DO construct and multiple loops ending on one statement are deleted features from the Fortran 2015 standard.

         call MPI_Reduce(cdiff,ccdiff,1,p3dfft_mpireal,MPI_MAX,0, &
                                        ^                           
ftn-297 crayftn: ERROR CHECK_RES, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 311, Column = 41 
  IMPLICIT NONE is specified in the host scope, therefore an explicit type must be specified for data object "P3DFFT_MPIREAL".

    real(p3dfft_type) A(istart(1):iend(1),istart(2):iend(2),istart(3):iend(3),nv)
         ^                                                                        
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR INIT_AR_SINE_MANY, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 337, Column = 7 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

    real(p3dfft_type) sinyz
         ^                  
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR INIT_AR_SINE_MANY, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 338, Column = 7 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      use p3dfft
          ^      
ftn-292 crayftn: ERROR MULT_ARRAY, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 378, Column = 11 
  "P3DFFT" is specified as the module name on a USE statement, but the compiler cannot find it.

      integer(i8) nar,i
              ^         
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR MULT_ARRAY, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 380, Column = 15 
  "I8" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      complex(p3dfft_type) X(nar)
              ^                   
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR MULT_ARRAY, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 381, Column = 15 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      real(p3dfft_type) f
           ^              
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR MULT_ARRAY, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 382, Column = 12 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      use p3dfft
          ^      
ftn-292 crayftn: ERROR PRINT_ALL, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 398, Column = 11 
  "P3DFFT" is specified as the module name on a USE statement, but the compiler cannot find it.

      integer(i8) i,Nar
              ^         
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR PRINT_ALL, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 401, Column = 15 
  "I8" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      complex(p3dfft_type) Ar(1,1,*)
              ^                      
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR PRINT_ALL, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 402, Column = 15 
  "P3DFFT_TYPE" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

      real(r8) Nglob
           ^         
ftn-297 crayftn: ERROR PRINT_ALL, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 404, Column = 12 
  IMPLICIT NONE is specified in the host scope, therefore an explicit type must be specified for data object "R8".
           ^         
ftn-868 crayftn: ERROR PRINT_ALL, File = driver_sine_many.F90, Line = 404, Column = 12 
  "R8" is used in a constant expression, therefore it must be a constant.

Cray Fortran : Version 8.6.x.x (20171205211118_bd28c7ad30c18500b9af2b56f7f8161417d6808d)
Cray Fortran : Thu Sep 20, 2018  14:18:56
Cray Fortran : Compile time:  0.0320 seconds
Cray Fortran : 981 source lines
Cray Fortran : 26 errors, 1 warnings, 0 other messages, 0 ansi
Cray Fortran : "explain ftn-message number" gives more information about each message.
Makefile:484: recipe for target 'driver_sine_many.o' failed
make[3]: *** [driver_sine_many.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/TMA_CFDLab/174100022/software/p3dfft-2.7.6/sample/FORTRAN'
Makefile:324: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/TMA_CFDLab/174100022/software/p3dfft-2.7.6/sample'
Makefile:425: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/TMA_CFDLab/174100022/software/p3dfft-2.7.6'
Makefile:345: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```